# HTML5 database issue while saving or selecting

Tags: javascript, database, html, web-sql

Spent hours but couldn't find what is the problem with the code.

The code simply creates a table if not exits and adds the text that typed in a textbox. On every load it loads these and writes to a list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mydb = null;

        function initDatabase() {
            try {
                if (!window.openDatabase) {
                    alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
                } else {
                    var shortName = 'mydb';
                    var version = '1.0';
                    var displayName = 'sample db';
                    var maxSize = 1024*1024*2;
                    mydb = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize, null);

                    mydb.transaction(
                        function (transaction) {
                            transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sampletable(term TEXT NOT NULL);', [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler);
                        }
                    );

                    loadDB();
                }
            } catch(e) {
                if (e == 2) {
                    alert("Invalid database version.");
                } else {
                    alert("Unknown error "+e+".");
                }
                return;
            }
        }

        function loadDB() {
            $(".debugger").html("");

            mydb.transaction(
                function (t) {
                    t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM sampletable", [],dataSelectHandler,errorHandler);
                }
            );
        }

        function saveDB(_term) {
            mydb.transaction(
                function (transaction) {
                    transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO sampletable(_term) VALUES (\""+_term + "\");");
                }
            );
        }

        function dataSelectHandler(transaction, results){
            $(".debugger").append("<li>Length: " + results.rows.length + "</li>");

            for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++)
            {
                var row = results.rows.item(i);         
                addToHistoryUI(row['_term']);
            }
        }

        function errorHandler(transaction, error){
            if (error.code==1){
                alert("DB Table already exists");
            } else {
                // Error is a human-readable string.
                alert('Oops.  Error was '+error.message+' (Code '+error.code+')');
            }
            return false;
        }


        function nullDataHandler(){
            //alert("SQL Query Succeeded");
        }

        function addToHistoryUI(_term)
        {
            var newH = "<li>" + _term + "</li>";
            $(".addedQueries").append(newH);
        }

        $(function () {
            initDatabase();
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".addBtn").click(function () {      
                var _term = $("#query").val();

                addToHistoryUI(_term);                  
                saveDB(_term);

                loadDB();
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div class="panel">
                <input id="query" type="text" name="query" />
                <a class="navigationLink addBtn" href="#">add</a>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <ul class="addedQueries">
                </ul>
            </div>

            <ul class="debugger"></ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the expected result, and what actually happens? It's hard to help without this information.

Comment: If also give IndexedDB a look since it's not going to be phased out like WebSQL will be.

Comment: Is Indexed DB support by anything yet? Last I heard, it was not.

Comment: There are vendor prefixed implementations, but nothing solid. You'd have to be using a Web-kit browser to use WebSQL anyway. I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your saveDB() method it looks like you are trying to use double quotes in your WHERE clause. Am I right about that?

Double quotes don't fly in SQL.

I am not sure why your SELECT would not be working. Please post the error message.

UPDATE: You're INSERT is also failing because you have a typo.

```
transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO sampletable(_term) VALUES (\""+_term + "\");");
```

You have INTO sampleTable(_term), but you don;t have a column called _term, the column name is term (with no underscore).  I made that change and the inserts now happen.

You also had some other minor stuff. This seems to do what you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mydb = null;

        function initDatabase() {
            try {
                if (!window.openDatabase) {
                    alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
                } else {
                    var shortName = 'mydb';
                    var version = '1.0';
                    var displayName = 'sample db';
                    var maxSize = 1024*1024*2;
                    mydb = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize, null);

                    mydb.transaction(
                        function (t) {
                            t.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sampletable(term TEXT NOT NULL);', [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler);
                        }
                    );

                    loadDB();
                }
            } catch(e) {
                if (e == 2) {
                    alert("Invalid database version.");
                } else {
                    alert("Unknown error "+e+".");
                }
                return;
            }
        }

        function loadDB() {
            $(".debugger").html("");
            $("li").remove();

            mydb.readTransaction(
                function (t) {
                    t.executeSql("SELECT term FROM sampletable", [],dataSelectHandler,errorHandler);
                }
            );
        }

        function saveDB(_term) {
            mydb.transaction(
                function (transaction) {
                    transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO sampletable(term) VALUES ('"+_term + "');");
                }
            );
        }

        function dataSelectHandler(t, results){

            $(".debugger").append("<li>Length: " + results.rows.length + "</li>");

            for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++)
            {   
                var row = results.rows.item(i);         
                addToHistoryUI(row['term']);     

            }
        }

        function errorHandler(transaction, error){
            if (error.code==1){
                alert("DB Table already exists");
            } else {
                // Error is a human-readable string.
                alert('Oops.  Error was '+error.message+' (Code '+error.code+')');
            }
            return false;
        }


        function nullDataHandler(){
            //alert("SQL Query Succeeded");
        }

        function addToHistoryUI(_term)
        {
            var newH = "<li>" + _term + "</li>";
            $(".addedQueries").append(newH);
        }

        $(function () {
            initDatabase();
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".addBtn").click(function () {      
                var _term = $("#query").val();

                addToHistoryUI(_term);                  
                saveDB(_term);

                loadDB();
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div class="panel">
                <input id="query" type="text" name="query" />
                <a class="navigationLink addBtn" href="#">add</a>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <ul class="addedQueries">
                </ul>
            </div>

            <ul class="debugger"></ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Changed it to transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO sampletable(_term) VALUES ('"+_term + "');"); but not worked again and also it doesn't give me an error unfortunatelly.

Comment: Well, I am done helping until you tell us what the error messages you get are.

Comment: Then why is the title of this question "HTML5 database error while saving or selecting"?